# Extract Values from three sheets into final sheet based upon the there names

Tags: excel, formulas

I have one workbook containing data in three sheets [Sheet1, Sheet2 and Sheet3] and fourth sheet is the main sheet.

I would like to add the values from three sheets into main sheet based upon the name if match.
for example,

```
Sheet 1
A,B [columns]
test1,1000
test2,2000

Sheet 2
A,B [columns]
test2,1000
test1,2000

Sheet 3
A,B [columns]
test1,1000
test2,2000
```

Expected Results...

```
Main Sheet
test1, 4000
test2, 5000
```

Can you please suggest me the formula or any reference for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's what you need - If I understood the input correctly, assuming you have `Sheet1:Sheet3` in your workbook and `SUM` sheet which is "main" (formulas are for the last one):

1. Type in `A1`: `test1` or any value you want to summarize.
2. Type in `B1`: `=SUM((Sheet1!A:A=A1)*Sheet1!B:B,(Sheet2!A:A=A1)*Sheet2!B:B,(Sheet3!A:A=A1)*Sheet3!B:B)`, but press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> instead of usual <kbd>ENTER</kbd> - this will define an ARRAY formula and will result in `{}` brackets around it (but do NOT type them manually!).
3. Add new values to sum up into `A` and autofill formula in `B` down as required.

Sample file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/95n46kavpfj4xs7/Sum3Sheets.xlsx

Answer (score 0):

The formula for test1 are:

```
    =Sheet1!A2+Sheet2!B2+Sheet3!A2
```

The formula for test2 are:

```
    =Sheet1!B2+Sheet2!A2+Sheet3!B2
```

Then use the Fill to fill this formula to all columns.

Updated:

```
HLOOKUP("Test2",Sheet1!A1:B2,2)+HLOOKUP("Test2",Sheet2!A1:B2,2)+HLOOKUP("Test2",Sheet3!A1:B2,2)
```

Comment: As mentioned, Can you suggest the formula based upon the name(test1) get the value and sum. I mean, if name='test1' in sheet1[range], sheet2[range] and sheet3[range] get the values and sum it.